# How to use regexp in alias & root in nginx?

Tags: nginx, location, alias, root

I need to service some file to users by nginx. It's different bitween user's request url and real file path in server. So I tried to use alias in location

request URL :
1) http://info.myservice.com/statement/**12345678**/12/34/A.html
2) http://info.myservice.com/statement/**57837873**/56/78/B.html
...

real path in server :
1) /data/statement/**0**/12/34/A.html 
2) /data/statement/**0**/56/78/B.html

location setting :

```
 location ~ /statement/[0-9]+ {
    if ($request_uri ~ "/(d+|-)(.*)") {
            #access_log off;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    }
    alias /data/statement/0;
}
```

but it doesn't work. need some advice..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `root` directive with a `rewrite ... break` to make the URL match the real path:

```
location /statement/ {
    root /data/statement/0;
    rewrite ^/statement/[0-9]+(/.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.